# Coin tossing game.

Tags: probability, expected-value

Consider the following game.
You're given a coin that has a 4/5 chance of landing on heads and 1/5 on tails. Each time the coin lands on heads you will win 10000 dollars. Before each toss you can decide to withdraw from the game with the money you've won or keep tossing to win more, however if the coin lands once on tails you will lose all. What would be the winning strategy here? More precisley, if $Y$ is the random variable "Total prize won", what is the number of tosses that maximizes $E[Y]$?

This seems kind of simple, but maybe I am wrong so that's why I'm asking. Isn't this just finding $n$ such that $n10000(\frac{4}{5})^n$ is maximized? Though I find it weird that 4 and 5 attain the same (and maximum) value.

Comment: When your bankroll reaches $40000$, the game is fair.

Comment: @saulspatz So, is 4 the ideal number of tosses?

Comment: $4$ tosses and $5$ give the same expected value, since the expected value of the fifth toss is $0$.  To choose between $4$ and $5$, you need some additional criterion.  Perhaps the standard deviation?

Comment: @saulspatz But if you get the same expected value from 4 and 5 tosses, wouldn't 4 be the ideal since you're getting the same expected value for 1 less toss?

Comment: @ManuelPico, the fact that you're getting the money for one less toss is already included in the definition of the expected value. Although it is true you are tossing less, the payoff is also smaller with 4 tosses.

Comment: @MeesdeVries So you're saying 5 is the ideal number?

Comment: @ManuelPico, you haven't defined "ideal", so it's an impossible to answer question.

Comment: @MeesdeVries The idea is to win as much money as possible, so I think 5 makes more sense but at the same time you're risking more with the extra toss... Unfortunately the problem doesn't give much more insight

Comment: Wouldn't the winning strategy be simply to keep tossing until your winnings reach $40000, then stop? I know you're discussing the number of rolls, but I don't think predetermining the number of rolls would be the same as devising a winning strategy.

Comment: I would say that stopping after $4$ is 'optimal conservative' and stopping after $5$ is 'optimal risky'.  (You may get more money if you take your chances on a fifth roll; but you are risking a sure 40000 dollars--assuming that you've gotten safely through four rolls.)

Comment: @A.J. You can only play the game once...